# How can I launch a file properties dialog from the command line?

Tags: windows, command-line, shell, properties

It's simple programmatically with ShellExecute to specify the `properties` verb when instructing Windows to open a file, but can this be done from the command line or run box?

Ideally I'd like to do this without an external program or script.

It appears to be possible by calling `ShellExecute` by using `rundll32.exe`, but not without the right parameters.

Answer (score 8):

**Quick tool:**

You could write a ridiculous script, or you could just use this awesome portable app shared by an SO user in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27696310/

> GeekDrop Props

[Github Share](https://github.com/STaRDoGG/GeekDrop-Props/releases)

**Usage:**

```
GDProps.exe FILEORFOLDERNAME [FILEORFOLDERNAME]...
```

**Example:**

```
e:\Tools\GDProps.exe "c:\users\Corrupt Profile" "c:\Windows" "c:\Program Files(x86)"
```

*^^ about twice a day Windows 10 corrupts a user profile somewhere so I need to go over and change various security permissions in these folders to perform my quick app-repair*

Answer (score 2):

I've looked into this several times over the years, but never found a solution, but I have a workaround.

I would like to easily edit the EXIF data on image files from the commend line, so I use the following batch script to open Explorer with the file selected:

```
@echo off

:: OpenLocation.cmd - Opens file or directory location in Explorer

if [%1]==[] (
        explorer /n, /select,"%CD%"
) ELSE (
        explorer /n, /select,"%~f1"
)

:EOF
```

Then I type <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> to open the Properties dialogue box.  You can use <kbd>TAB</kbd> and the arrow keys to navigate it, so you don't need to reach for the mouse.

Answer (score 0):

You can use start->run [rundll32](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/q164787/) with ...

```
rundll32 shell32.dll,ShellExecute [args]
```

... but I'm not sure the args you would use to get the properties.

Comment: Jim Barry, MVP for Windows SDK says : Unfortunately ShellExec_RunDLL doesn't provide any way to specify a verb. I can't think of a simple way of doing it either. "Properties" is a "verb" in Windows SDK parlance.

Comment: Anybody know what the arguments would be?

Comment: There is no arguments that will open the properties via this method.

Answer (score 0):

Can you use a custom executable instead?

You can code your own in C or VB6, and then build a small executable file,

or you could use the verinfo.exe

http://www.portablefreeware.com/?id=1937

or the filever.exe from microsoft

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/913111