# How can I specify what action (run/open/edit) I want to execute on given file in the command line window?

Tags: windows, command-line, file-association

Is it possible to specify what action (run/open/edit) I want to execute on a given file in the command line window? If so how?

Comment: Related: [How can I launch a file properties dialog from the command line?](http://superuser.com/questions/13290/)

Answer (score 0):

### Windows

Run/Open: `file` or `start file`
Edit: `notepad file`

### Linux (Gnome environment)

Run: `./file`.
Edit: `gedit file` (for text files)
Open: `gnome-run file`

Replace `file` by the filename.

Comment: The OP tagged it "Windows"....

Comment: Oops. -------------

Comment: So why the -1 then?

Answer (score 0):

Use the DOS command `assoc` to modify the file extension associations.  Do

```
assoc /?
```

to see the help for it.